# DataGridView System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 0 does not have a value when closing form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Please help me find the source of this error:

```
Error happened Display: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 0 does not have a value.
at System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
at
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridview.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowIndex)
```

This error only appears when Im closing the form and wont go away. Index 0 just keeps on incrementing everytime i click on OK.

It does not encounter any problem when loading the form.

Here is my entire code:

```
public partial class frmSalesOrders : Form
{
    public frmSalesOrders()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmSalesOrders_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Enabled = false;
        this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsSalesOrders.users);
        this.companiesTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsSalesOrders.companies);
        this.salesordersTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsSalesOrders.salesorders);
        this.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void btnSOFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string key = tbSOFilterKey.Text;
            int custid = Convert.ToInt32(cbSOFilterByCustomer.SelectedValue);
            string startdate = dtpSOFilterStartDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
            string enddate = dtpSOFilterEndDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
            salesordersBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("comp = '{0}' AND (sonumber LIKE '%{1}%' OR ponumber LIKE '%{1}%') AND podate > '{2}' AND podate <'{3}'", custid, key, startdate, enddate);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Error on Filter of Sales Orders", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if(res == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                string key = tbSOFilterKey.Text;
                int custid = Convert.ToInt32(cbSOFilterByCustomer.SelectedValue);
                string startdate = dtpSOFilterStartDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
                string enddate = dtpSOFilterEndDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
                salesordersBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("comp = '{0}' AND (sonumber LIKE '%{1}%' OR ponumber LIKE '%{1}%') AND podate > '{2}' AND podate <'{3}'", custid, key, startdate, enddate);
            }
            else
            {
                tbSOFilterKey.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSOClearFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            tbSOFilterKey.Clear();
            cbSOFilterByCustomer.SelectedValue = 0;
            dtpSOFilterStartDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1970");
            dtpSOFilterEndDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
            salesordersBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Error on Clearing Filter of Sales Orders", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (res == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                tbSOFilterKey.Clear();
                cbSOFilterByCustomer.SelectedValue = 0;
                dtpSOFilterStartDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1970");
                dtpSOFilterEndDate.Value = DateTime.Now;
                salesordersBindingSource.RemoveFilter();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnCancelChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            salesordersBindingSource.CancelEdit();
            formatOrderAmt();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Error on Cancellation of Changes to Sales Orders", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if(res == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                salesordersBindingSource.CancelEdit();
                formatOrderAmt();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSaveChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cbSOLastModBy.SelectedValue = UserDetails.userid;
            tbSOLastModOn.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            int rowIndex = dGridSalesOrdersList.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            this.Enabled = false;

            this.Validate();
            this.salesordersBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.salesordersTableAdapter.Update(dsSalesOrders.salesorders);
            this.salesordersTableAdapter.Fill(dsSalesOrders.salesorders);

            this.dGridSalesOrdersList.ClearSelection();
            this.dGridSalesOrdersList.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;

            this.Enabled = true;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Error on Saving of Changes to Sales Orders", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (res == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                cbSOLastModBy.SelectedValue = UserDetails.userid;
                tbSOLastModOn.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

                int rowIndex = dGridSalesOrdersList.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                this.Enabled = false;

                this.Validate();
                this.salesordersBindingSource.EndEdit();
                this.salesordersTableAdapter.Update(dsSalesOrders.salesorders);
                this.salesordersTableAdapter.Fill(dsSalesOrders.salesorders);

                this.dGridSalesOrdersList.ClearSelection();
                this.dGridSalesOrdersList.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;

                this.Enabled = true;
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
            else
            {
                this.salesordersBindingSource.CancelEdit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSONew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.dGridSalesOrdersList.ClearSelection();
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) salesordersBindingSource.AddNew();
            drv["sonumber"] = "Auto";
            drv["status"] = false;
            drv["cancelled"] = false;
            drv["podate"] = DateTime.Now;
            drv["orderamt"] = 0;
            drv["createdby"] = UserDetails.userid;
            drv["createdon"] = DateTime.Now;
            drv["lastmodby"] = UserDetails.userid;
            drv["lastmodon"] = DateTime.Now;
            this.dGridSalesOrdersList.CurrentCell.Selected = true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Error on Adding New Sales Orders", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (res == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                this.dGridSalesOrdersList.ClearSelection();
                DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)salesordersBindingSource.AddNew();
                drv["sonumber"] = "Auto";
                drv["status"] = false;
                drv["cancelled"] = false;
                drv["podate"] = DateTime.Now;
                drv["orderamt"] = 0;
                drv["createdby"] = UserDetails.userid;
                drv["createdon"] = DateTime.Now;
                drv["lastmodby"] = UserDetails.userid;
                drv["lastmodon"] = DateTime.Now;
                this.dGridSalesOrdersList.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.salesordersBindingSource.CancelEdit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void frmSalesOrders_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.salesordersBindingSource.CancelEdit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Error on Closing Form", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (res == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                this.salesordersBindingSource.CancelEdit();
            }
            else
            {
                this.salesordersBindingSource.CancelEdit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSOViewMoreDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            this.Enabled = false;
            soSelected.soid = Convert.ToInt32(tbSOSequence.Text);
            frmSODetails soDetails = new frmSODetails();
            soDetails.ShowDialog();
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            this.salesordersTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsSalesOrders.salesorders);
            this.Enabled = true;
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Error on Viewing Sales Order Details", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (res == DialogResult.Retry)
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                this.Enabled = false;
                soSelected.soid = Convert.ToInt32(tbSOSequence.Text);
                frmSODetails soDetails = new frmSODetails();
                soDetails.ShowDialog();
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                this.salesordersTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsSalesOrders.salesorders);
                this.Enabled = true;
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
            else
            {
                frmSODetails soDetails = new frmSODetails();
                soDetails.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void formatOrderAmt()
    {
        if(tbSOPOAmount.TextLength > 0)
        {
            decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(tbSOPOAmount.Text);
            tbSOPOAmount.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse(amount.ToString()));
        }
        else
        {
            tbSOPOAmount.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", double.Parse("0.00"));
        }

    }

    private void dGridSalesOrdersList_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs anError)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error happened " + anError.Context.ToString() + " : "+ anError.Exception.ToString());

        if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Commit error");
        }
        if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.CurrentCellChange)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cell change");
        }
        if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Parsing)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("parsing error");
        }
        if (anError.Context == DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.LeaveControl)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("leave control error");
        }

        if ((anError.Exception) is ConstraintException)
        {
            DataGridView view = (DataGridView)sender;
            view.Rows[anError.RowIndex].ErrorText = "an error";
            view.Rows[anError.RowIndex].Cells[anError.ColumnIndex].ErrorText = "an error";

            anError.ThrowException = false;
        }
    }

    private void dGridSalesOrdersList_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //formatOrderAmt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this really addresses the issue or just a quickfix.

I tried implementing one suggestion from [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1e1b048f-ffa2-4001-8a59-42c496572e6c/indexoutofrangeexception-on-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols) which is to dispose the DataGridView and the BindingSource on Form_Closed Event and the error did go away.

Code:

```
private void frmSalesOrders_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        usersBindingSourceSOCreatedBy.Dispose();
        usersBindingSourceSOLastModBy.Dispose();
        companiesBindingSource.Dispose();
        salesordersBindingSource.Dispose();
        dGridSalesOrdersList.Dispose();
    }
```